GoRouter - Browser Back Button Navigation Issue in Flutter Web (Page Order Not Preserved)
I'm using GoRouter for navigation in my Flutter web app. When I navigate through pages 1 to 4 and use the app's back button to go back to page 3, it works as expected. However, when I click the browser's back button from page 3, the navigation order is reversed, taking me back to page 4, then 3, 2, and finally 1.
I'm trying to understand why the browser back button behaves differently from the app's back button in GoRouter and how to ensure the expected navigation order is maintained using both methods.
void main() {
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Navigation',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      routerConfig: AppRouter.router,
    );
  }
}


class Nav {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
  static BuildContext context = navigatorKey.currentContext!;

  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> getKey() {
    return navigatorKey;
  }

  static to(String route, {BuildContext? buildContext, Object? extra}) {
    return (buildContext ?? context).push(route, extra: extra);
  }

  static void off(String route, {Object? extra}) {
    context.replace(route, extra: extra);
  }

  static void offAll(String route, {BuildContext? buildContext, Object? extra}) {
    while (context.canPop()) {
      log("message");
      context.pop();
    }

    (buildContext ?? context).go(route);
  }

  static void back({BuildContext? buildContext, Object? extra}) {
    try {
      GoRouter.of(buildContext ?? context).pop();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}


class AppRouter {
  static _getRouteData<T>(GoRouterState state, [String? key]) {
    if (state.extra != null) {
      final args = state.extra as Map;
      return args[key ?? "data"] as T;
    } else {
      switch (T) {
        case const (String):
          return "";

        case const (int):
          return 0;

        case const (double):
          return 0.0;

        case const (bool):
          return 0;

        case const (List):
          return [];

        default:
          return "";
      }
    }
  }

  static GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: Nav.getKey(),
    initialLocation: Routes.DASHBOARD,
    observers: [NavigatorObserver()],
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.DASHBOARD,
        path: Routes.DASHBOARD,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return const Dashboard();
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: Routes.PAGE1,
            path: Routes.PAGE1.subRoute,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => Page2Bloc(),
                child: const Page1(),
              );
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: Routes.PAGE2,
            path: Routes.PAGE2.subRoute,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Page2(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                routeData: _getRouteData<double>(state),
              );
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: Routes.PAGE3,
            path: Routes.PAGE3.subRoute,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return const Page3();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
    errorPageBuilder: (context, state) {
      return const MaterialPage(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("404 Not Found!"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}


class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({super.key});

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dashboard"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            
            Nav.to(Routes.PAGE1, buildContext: context);
          },
          child: const Text("Go to page 1"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  int value = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Init Called!");
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateValue() {
    setState(() {
      value = 6;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Page 1"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<Page2Bloc, Page2State>(builder: (context, state) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(state.value.toString()),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.read<Page2Bloc>().updateValue();
                },
                child: const Text("Update"),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Nav.to(Routes.PAGE2, extra: {"data": 1.5}, buildContext: context);
                },
                child: const Text("Go to page 2"),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key, required this.routeData});

  final double routeData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Page 2"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Route Data : $routeData"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Nav.to(Routes.PAGE3, buildContext: context);
              },
              child: const Text("Go to page 3"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: const Text("Page 3"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Nav.back(buildContext: context);
              },
              child: const Text("Back"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Nav.offAll(Routes.DASHBOARD, buildContext: context);
              },
              child: const Text("Dashboard"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

